# Template-expanding directives not rendering on the DOM

Tags: angularjs

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkeo5hqw/) demonstration of a problem I've been facing, where my template-expanding directives are not functioning correctly.

In the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkeo5hqw/), there are three buttons, where each toggles a different colored box.

```
redBox {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

// etc, etc.
```

Clicking a button toggles the display of one of the colored boxes.

```
<body ng-app="boxApp">
    <div ng-controller="NavCtrl">
        <nav>
            <button ng-click="shownSection = 'red'">Show red box</button>
            <button ng-click="shownSection = 'blue'">Show blue box</button>
            <button ng-click="shownSection = 'green'">Show green box</button>
        </nav>

        <article>
            <redBox ng-show="shownSection == 'red'"></redBox>
            <blueBox ng-show="shownSection == 'blue'"></blueBox>
            <greenBox ng-show="shownSection == 'green'"></greenBox>
        </article>
    </div>
</body>
```

Lastly, each `fooBox` element corresponds to an AngularJS directive that I would like to create a new DOM element based on a simple template.

```
var app = angular.module("boxApp", []);

app.controller("NavCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.shownSection = "";            
});

app.directive('redBox', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<div>red box</div>',
    }
});

app.directive('greenBox', function() { 
   return {
      // etc.
   }
});
```

It doesn't work. In fact, the application behaves the same way regardless of whether or not I define the directives in the first place: it toggles each DOM element as intended, but displays the element as empty - ignoring the `height` and `width` properties but not the `border` property.

I assumed that the `fooBox` elements would render on the page because AngularJS would recognize these directives when it initially traverses the DOM, but it doesn't seem to do anything, and I don't get any console errors.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things.

You named your directives `redBox / blueBox / greenBox` the camel-case means a `-` goes between the letters.

So in the html it needs to look like this:

```
<red-box />
<blue-box />
<green-box />
```

Your CSS also needs to change to `red-box { }`.

Also put `display:block;` within your CSS for the blocks. That's why the height & width are being ignored.

[jsFiddle updated*](http://jsfiddle.net/mcpDESIGNS/Lkeo5hqw/3/)

Comment: This makes sense, but this doesn't fix my bigger problem.  Each directive has `template:'<div>foo box</div>'`, but the templates do not render correctly.  If I remove all of the directives from the code, the behavior is the same. http://jsfiddle.net/zwta253k/

Comment: Updated the jsfiddle, I didn't notice the directive issue!

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this fixed my problem.  I can't believe the main issue boiled down to improper use of camel casing.  Is there any chance you can tell me why there is a forced naming convention difference between the directive names and the DOM element names?

Comment: Well HTML is always all lowercase. The reason they use a camelCase like that is because angular actually looks for many different types of template names. Attribute directives for example could have many different ways for the same thing. `data-red-box` `data:red:box` `x-red-box` etc etc. This makes the directive name ambiguous to which way it should be put in the HTML. Hope that helps!